# Calculate distance between 2 points in shiny

Tags: r, math, shiny, reactive-programming, shinydashboard

I want to calculate the distance of the segment between 2 clicked points, i already have a function with that launches a shiny dashboard that allows you to save the clicks and draw a line between the pairs. It is printing the dimension of the image in pixels. Any image can be used changing the image_path.

I want to know if there is a way to select the segments of each pair and calculate the distance between them in pixels and later convert it to cm.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(imager)
library(reactable)

click_length <- function(image_path = system.file("example_images", package = "ClickMetrics")){
  app <- shinyApp(
    ui <- dashboardPage(
      skin = 'purple',
      dashboardHeader(title = "ClickMetrics"),
      dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
      dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
          box(plotOutput("IMG", 
                         height = 400,
                         click = "click_plot")),
          
          box(
            (selectInput("IMAGE",
                         "Images:",
                         list.files(path = image_path,
                                    pattern = ".jpg",
                                    full.names = TRUE,
                                    include.dirs = FALSE)))
            
          ),
          
          actionButton("clear","Clear Points"),
          
          reactableOutput("INFO")
          
        )
      )
    ),
    
    server <- function(input, output, session){
      
      # Creating a reactive value that receives image input
      
      img <- reactive({
        f <- input$IMAGE
        imager::load.image(f)
      })
      
      # Store reactive values for coordinates
      
      CLICKS <- reactiveValues(
        x = NULL,
        y = NULL,
        n = NULL,
        pair = NULL
      )
      
      ns <- session$ns
      
      observeEvent(eventExpr = input$click_plot$x, handlerExpr = { ## Adds the info about clicks
        CLICKS$x <- append(CLICKS$x, input$click_plot$x)
        CLICKS$y <- append(CLICKS$y, input$click_plot$y)
        CLICKS$n <- append(CLICKS$n, length(CLICKS$x))
        CLICKS$pair <-
          append(CLICKS$pair,
                 as.integer(ceiling(length(CLICKS$x)/2)))
        df <- data.frame(CLICKS$x, CLICKS$y, CLICKS$pair)
        df <- split(df, CLICKS$pair)
        print(dim(img())) # prints dimensions of the image 
      })
      
      output$IMG <- renderPlot({
        expr = {
          img <- img()
          par(mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 1.75, 0.5))
          plot(img, axes = FALSE)
          box(col = 'gray')
          mtext(text = input$IMAGE,
                side = 3,
                line = 0.5,
                adj = 0.5,
                cex = 1.23)
          if (!is.null(CLICKS$x) && length(CLICKS$x) > 0) {
            points(x = CLICKS$x,
                   y = CLICKS$y,
                   pch = 19,
                   cex = 0.75,
                   col = "red")
            text(x = CLICKS$x,
                 y = CLICKS$y,
                 label = CLICKS$n,
                 pos = 3)
            n_par <- 2 * floor(length(CLICKS$x)/2)
            tb_pairs <- cbind(
              matrix(CLICKS$x[1:n_par], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
              matrix(CLICKS$y[1:n_par], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
            segments(x0 = tb_pairs[, 1],
                     x1 = tb_pairs[, 2],
                     y0 = tb_pairs[, 3],
                     y1 = tb_pairs[, 4],
                     col = "black")
          }
        }
      })
      
      output$INFO <- renderReactable({
        df1 <- data.frame(round(CLICKS$x,2), round(CLICKS$y,2), CLICKS$pair)
        reactable(df1)
      })
      
      observe({ # clear clicked points
        if(input$clear>0){
          session$reload()
        }
      })
      
    })
  
  runApp(app)
}

click_length()
```

I tried some examples using locator, but it does not work inside a shiny dashboard, which i need.